# embedding or linking html file in Powerpoint using python and pptx

Tags: python, html, plotly, python-pptx

I'm trying to create a link on my power point slide to a local HTML file that i'd like to open up. I have a plotly figure exported as both an HTML file and a PNG, where I want to have the PNG on the power point slide to show the figure, and then either want to click the image, or a seperate icon to the side, to open the HTML figure so there is an interactive view of the data. Here are the things I've tried.

I can insert the PNG's into the slides without any problem, and I tired doing `shape.click_action.hyperlink.address = os.path.realpath(htmlPath)` to open the figure, but that didn't work, it just opens a file browser to the location where the power point is saved (not even to the html file).

I can manually add a sperate icon that will open the html file (Insert>Object>Create from file> "html file path"), and that works. if I save that power point file as an XML and try to look at the progid of the html file, I only shows `progId="Package"`. If i try to do the same thing in python using `shape = shapes.add_ole_object(htmlPath, 'Package', left=Inches(1), top=Inches(3))` it will insert an object, but then going to click on the object I always get an error saying "Embedded object is corrupted or has an emtpy file name". Below is the full code I used for this, here the testBlank.pptx file is just a power point file with two slides, the first is a title slide, and the second is a blank slide where I'm trying to create a link to the HTML file

```
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx import Presentation


htmlPath = r'C:\Users\myUser\Documents\testing\htmlFigure.html'

outFile = 'testChanged.pptx'
testPrs = Presentation('testBlank.pptx')
shapes =testPrs.slides[1].shapes # go to the second slide, which is blank
shape = shapes.add_ole_object(htmlPath, 'Package', left=Inches(1), top=Inches(3))
testPrs.save(outFile)
```

I've tried searching, but can't find a different way of embedding or linking the file. Has anyone else had any luck with this?

Comment: I can manually add a sperate icon that will open the html file (Insert>Object>Create from file> "html file path"), and `that works`. Here it works with you but manually, right?

Comment: correct, I can do it manually and the HTMl opens fine then, but if I try to do the same thing but using python by trying to add a OLE object, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does a `file:` URL work?

Comment: well... that does indeed work. I tried using that before by doing `shape.click_action.hyperlink.address = os.path.realpath(filename)` , and that wasn't working, but that's because most of the file paths had a # character in it, and that was what was causing the problem... so now i've got to figure how to handle those special symbols. if you'd like to post that as an answer I'm happy to accept it. I'm glad I tried it that way again and just happened to use a path that didn't have any special characters in it